# Confusion about calculating right Hash size

Tags: hashtable, hash

I am a bit confused on choosing the right hash size. Say for example if I want to hash 2^32 values, is it okay to use hash size of 32 bits? Would it cause more collisions? I read somewhere about the rule of square roots..Does it mean ideally I should choose a 64bit hash size? But then doesn't it imply that the space required for storing hashtable will be for ~ storing 2^64 values.
This is the part that confuses me. Hashing by definition is reducing the key space, but if I am storing 2^32 values in the bloated 2^64 values space...that doesn't sound right. I am increasing the keyspace. I guess I am misunderstanding something...any help to clarify this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) says it best:

> A hash function is any algorithm or subroutine that maps **large data sets** of **variable length**, called keys, to smaller data sets of a **fixed length**.

It does not sound like this is what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you are trying to map a 32-bit keys to 32-bit values.  There are many possible uses for a hash function.  What you are describing doesn't seem like an ideal use case for a hash function.